# Laravel 8 - Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, api, collections, resources

I'm trying to create Collection to return specific fields on API requests on Laravel 8. My Resource file:

```
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name
        ];
    }
```

When I'm trying to get all Users I'm getting this error :

```
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

My api.php

```
    Route::get('/users', function () {
        return new UsersResource(User::all());
    });
```

Do I need to write something in the Model in order to make that work?

Comment: Has the model contain name in $fillable array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `UserResource` from`JsonResource`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;


class UsersResource extends JsonResource
{
  
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'name' => $this->name
        ];
    }
}
```

And
then you can do the following

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return UsersResource::collection(User::all());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your route code to

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return UsersResource::collection(User::all());
});
```

see docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections

Comment: I'm getting the same result. I cleared routes cache